# Processing some JSON to output a a JSON object that represents a folder structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, functional-programming

Given the following two json objects, where `files` represents an array of directories and `colourCodes` represents a mapping from a colour to `status`, I want to process the array of files (which is actually a list of directories) to determine a directory structure. In each  `file` the `folderColorRgb` maps to a status (the status can be looked up from the `colourCodes` constant - if the colour doesn't exist  in `colourCodes` then the status is `Not covered`).

```
const colourCodes = {
    '#4986e7': 'Covered 100%',
    '#f83a22': 'Covered - weak',
}


const files = [
    {
        id: '1nn7_JlbwQCxyz7qecqEtbWvY4C9Q2S3M',
        name: 'cell biology',
        parents: [ '1YewXh1WkIVIxOuHTV9acYG7WDE55EnPR' ],
    },
    {
        id: '1bcNxav7kq--E1Qabu3tcXk9DxvRdCcgR',
        name: 'ecology',
        parents: [ '1YewXh1WkIVIxOuHTV9acYG7WDE55EnPR' ],
        folderColorRgb: '#4986e7'
    },
    {
        id: '1MmkaP5xveClf6BfrhjHyYv4Q_Vaq1vf_',
        name: 'infection and response',
        parents: [ '1YewXh1WkIVIxOuHTV9acYG7WDE55EnPR' ],
        folderColorRgb: '#8f8f8f'
    },
    {
        id: '1YewXh1WkIVIxOuHTV9acYG7WDE55EnPR',
        name: 'biology',
        parents: [ '1WVm7S1fw8Neg7FM80QNxcMWvVc_w_Jt2' ],
        folderColorRgb: '#16a765'
    },
    {
        id: '1WVm7S1fw8Neg7FM80QNxcMWvVc_w_Jt2',
        name: 'science',
        parents: [ '0AF24wY_V36dlUk9PVA' ],
        folderColorRgb: '#a47ae2'
    },
    {
        id: 'physics-id',
        name: 'physics',
        parents: [ '1WVm7S1fw8Neg7FM80QNxcMWvVc_w_Jt2' ],
        folderColorRgb: '#16a765'
    },

    {
        id: 'electricity-id',
        name: 'electricity',
        parents: [ 'physics-id' ],
        folderColorRgb: '#f83a22'
    },
]
```

The result I want to achieve  is as follows:

```
{
  science: {
    biology: {
      'cell biology': { status: 'Not covered' },
      ecology: { status: 'Covered 100%' },
      'infection and response': { status: 'Not covered' },
    },
    physics: { electricity: { status: 'Covered - weak' } },
  },
}
```

So it's the folder structure of the `files` array represented in JSON. You can make the following assumptions

- The `parents` array of each file will always contain one `parentId`, that is the link to the parent folder.
- All `parentId's` exist as a `id` in the file array - except for the top level directory (e.g. science in this case, the parentId for science does not exist in `files`.

Anyone know of a nice way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it helps to first tranform your input to a format that has just the things you need:

```
const Node = ({ id, name, parents: [parentId], folderColorRgb }) => ({
  id,
  name,
  parentId,
  status: colourCodes[folderColorRgb] || null,
  children: []
});
```

Writing the function that outputs the desired format is now easier to do:

```
Node.toObj = node => ({
  [node.name]: node.children.length
    ? Object.assign(...node.children.map(Node.toObj))
    : { status: node.status || "Not covered" }
});
```

Now the challenge is to:

- Link up the children to their parent
- Find the root node

I opted for creating an index of `{ nodeId: node }` and a single `forEach` that creates the links and stores the root node:

```
const foldersById = Object.fromEntries(
  files
    .map(Node)
    .map(f => [f.id, f])
);

// Note: this mutates the nodes
let root = null;
Object
  .values(foldersById)
  .forEach(f => {
    const parent = foldersById[f.parentId];
    if (parent) parent.children.push(f);
    else root = f;
  });
```

Then, you output the result by calling `Node.toObj(root)`.

The full code in a runnable snippet:

```js
const colourCodes = {
  '#4986e7': 'Covered 100%',
  '#f83a22': 'Covered - weak',
}


const files = [{
    id: '1nn7_JlbwQCxyz7qecqEtbWvY4C9Q2S3M',
    name: 'cell biology',
    parents: ['1YewXh1WkIVIxOuHTV9acYG7WDE55EnPR'],
  },
  {
    id: '1bcNxav7kq--E1Qabu3tcXk9DxvRdCcgR',
    name: 'ecology',
    parents: ['1YewXh1WkIVIxOuHTV9acYG7WDE55EnPR'],
    folderColorRgb: '#4986e7'
  },
  {
    id: '1MmkaP5xveClf6BfrhjHyYv4Q_Vaq1vf_',
    name: 'infection and response',
    parents: ['1YewXh1WkIVIxOuHTV9acYG7WDE55EnPR'],
    folderColorRgb: '#8f8f8f'
  },
  {
    id: '1YewXh1WkIVIxOuHTV9acYG7WDE55EnPR',
    name: 'biology',
    parents: ['1WVm7S1fw8Neg7FM80QNxcMWvVc_w_Jt2'],
    folderColorRgb: '#16a765'
  },
  {
    id: '1WVm7S1fw8Neg7FM80QNxcMWvVc_w_Jt2',
    name: 'science',
    parents: ['0AF24wY_V36dlUk9PVA'],
    folderColorRgb: '#a47ae2'
  },
  {
    id: 'physics-id',
    name: 'physics',
    parents: ['1WVm7S1fw8Neg7FM80QNxcMWvVc_w_Jt2'],
    folderColorRgb: '#16a765'
  },

  {
    id: 'electricity-id',
    name: 'electricity',
    parents: ['physics-id'],
    folderColorRgb: '#f83a22'
  },
]



const Node = ({
  id,
  name,
  parents: [parentId],
  folderColorRgb
}) => ({
  id,
  name,
  parentId,
  status: colourCodes[folderColorRgb] || null,
  children: []
});

Node.toObj = node => ({
  [node.name]: node.children.length ?
    Object.assign(...node.children.map(Node.toObj)) :
    { status: node.status || "Not covered" }
});



const foldersById = Object.fromEntries(
  files
  .map(Node)
  .map(f => [f.id, f])
);

// Note: this mutates the nodes
let root = null;
Object
  .values(foldersById)
  .forEach(f => {
    const parent = foldersById[f.parentId];
    if (parent) parent.children.push(f);
    else root = f;
  });

console.log(Node.toObj(root));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @user3297291, that's a very neat solution. I'm going to accept an answer on Wednesday.. at the moment you definitely have the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ive come up with the following solution, but will not accept my own answer and will leave the question open  to see if anyone has a more elegant way of doing it

```
const colourCodes = {
    '#4986e7': 'Covered 100%',
    '#f83a22': 'Covered - weak',
}


const files = [
    {
        id: '1nn7_JlbwQCxyz7qecqEtbWvY4C9Q2S3M',
        name: 'cell biology',
        parents: [ '1YewXh1WkIVIxOuHTV9acYG7WDE55EnPR' ],
    },
    {
        id: '1bcNxav7kq--E1Qabu3tcXk9DxvRdCcgR',
        name: 'ecology',
        parents: [ '1YewXh1WkIVIxOuHTV9acYG7WDE55EnPR' ],
        folderColorRgb: '#4986e7'
    },
    {
        id: '1MmkaP5xveClf6BfrhjHyYv4Q_Vaq1vf_',
        name: 'infection and response',
        parents: [ '1YewXh1WkIVIxOuHTV9acYG7WDE55EnPR' ],
        folderColorRgb: '#8f8f8f'
    },
    {
        id: '1YewXh1WkIVIxOuHTV9acYG7WDE55EnPR',
        name: 'biology',
        parents: [ '1WVm7S1fw8Neg7FM80QNxcMWvVc_w_Jt2' ],
        folderColorRgb: '#16a765'
    },
    {
        id: '1WVm7S1fw8Neg7FM80QNxcMWvVc_w_Jt2',
        name: 'science',
        parents: [ '0AF24wY_V36dlUk9PVA' ],
        folderColorRgb: '#a47ae2'
    },
    {
        id: 'physics-id',
        name: 'physics',
        parents: [ '1WVm7S1fw8Neg7FM80QNxcMWvVc_w_Jt2' ],
        folderColorRgb: '#16a765'
    },

    {
        id: 'electricity-id',
        name: 'electricity',
        parents: [ 'physics-id' ],
        folderColorRgb: '#f83a22'
    },
]

function getStatus(folder) {
    return colourCodes[folder.folderColorRgb] || 'Not covered'
}

function extractFolderStructure(parentFolder) {

    const children = files.filter(f => f.parents.includes(parentFolder.id))
    if (children.length==0) {
        const status = getStatus(parentFolder)
        return {[parentFolder.name]: {status}}
    }
    const childObjects = children.map(c => {
        const returnObj = extractFolderStructure(c)
        return returnObj
    })

    const fullObj = {[parentFolder.name] : {}}
    childObjects.forEach(co => {
        fullObj[parentFolder.name][Object.keys(co)[0]] = co[Object.keys(co)[0]]
    })

    return fullObj
}

console.log(extractFolderStructure(files.find(f => f.name === 'science')))
```